# rearrange the data based on a pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I've a file like this,

```
A1: abc.com B1: Hi there
B1: Your Test mail  A1: gml.com
B1: Your new mail   A1: hml.com
A1: def.com B1: Test email
B1: hello world A1: yml.com
```

I want to always pick the `A1: <string>` part first followed by the `B1: <string>` part.

I've tried `grep` and `awk` like below

```
 grep -Po '(?<=A1:)\W*\K[^ ]*' file.txt 
 awk -F"A1:|B1:" '{print $1 $2}' file.txt
```

But they're not giving the exact results

I want the output to be like this:

```
 A1: abc.com   B1: Hi there
 A1: gml.com   B1: Your Test mail   
 A1: hml.com  B1: Your new mail 
 A1: def.com  B1: Test email
 A1: yml.com  B1: hello world
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could leave the lines starting with `A1` as is and re-arrange those starting with `B1`

```
# if -E or -r is not supported: sed 's/\(B1:.*\)\(A1:.*\)/\2 \1/' ip.txt
$ sed -E 's/(B1:.*)(A1:.*)/\2 \1/' ip.txt
A1: abc.com B1: Hi there
A1: gml.com B1: Your Test mail  
A1: hml.com B1: Your new mail   
A1: def.com B1: Test email
A1: yml.com B1: hello world
```

- `.*` is greedy, so this solution assumes that `A1:` and `B1:` are unique in each line
- `(B1:.*)(A1:.*)` are two capture groups - to satisfy the entire expression, the first one will capture all string from `B1:` up to just before `A1:`. The second one will capture string from `A1:` till end of line
- `\2 \1` re-arranging the captured strings with space in between
- Further reading: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions

With `awk`

```
$ awk -F'A1:' '{print $1 ~ /B1:/ ? FS $2 " " $1 : $0}' ip.txt
A1: abc.com B1: Hi there
A1: gml.com B1: Your Test mail  
A1: hml.com B1: Your new mail   
A1: def.com B1: Test email
A1: yml.com B1: hello world
```

If first field contains `B1:`, re-arrange the fields, else print the input line as is

Answer (score 0):

We may do this using the following method:

```
perl -F'/(A1:|B1:)/' -lane '
   my %h = @F[1..$#F];
   print map { "$_$h{$_} " } qw/A1: B1:/;
' input.txt
```

**Output:**

```
A1: gml.com B1: Your Test mail   
A1: abc.com  B1: Hi there 
A1: hml.com B1: Your new mail    
A1: def.com  B1: Test email 
A1: yml.com B1: hello world
```

**Explanation:**

- split each record on A1: and/or B1: plus include the "splitters" as well.
- the first field in the @F array should be ignored. hence, there are even number of elements in the @F array which are then stored as a hash %h, with the keys being "A1:" and "B1:".
- We now iterate over the prescribed order via an anonymous array, qw/.../, and print the results to stdout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't want to use perl as Im writing a bash script :)